# To verify the email address on thank you page using cypress

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I am trying to automate the following:
I want to verify the email address on a thank you page by writing cypress commands.

Also, how can I have this email I’d in a constant or variable so that I needed not every time hardcode it and this email address entered on question page, I want to verify it on the thank you page.

Comment: Can you add the HTML you're trying to run this test against? And an example of what Cypress commands you've already tried?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, so I was planning to write cy.get and then verify the email having html tag like <p>email</p>